# Property resolution policy

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I need to resolve property injection based on the PropertyInfo.Name. The class looks like this

```
public class Test
{
    [Dependency]
    public Test TestProperty1{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to somehow be able to resolve TestProperty1 like this ***behind the scenes***, without explicitly retyping the property name.

```
container.Resolve<Test>("TestProperty1")
```

During a call to either `container.Resolve<Test>()` or `container.BuildUp( new Test())` **

How can I do this?

Comment: There is something wrong with your design. Resolving `Test` would probably cause a stack overflow exception, since it depends on itself. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. You want Unity to populate `TestProperty1` without telling it to do so?

Using the `DependencyAttribute` is not a good choice. [This article explains why](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/27/WhatsSoDangerousAboutADIAttribute.aspx).

To instruct Unity to inject a value into `TestProperty1` you have to modify the registration code:

```
container.RegisterType<Test>(new InjectionProperty("TestProperty1"));
```

A call to resolve will return an instance of `Test` with its `TestProperty1` filled.

If you have an existing instance of `Test` a call to `container.BuildUp()` will also inject some value into `TestProperty1`.